# Почему при обращении из локального класса к переменной окружающего класса, после её явной инициализации показывает её как null?

Tags: java

Почему при обращении из локального класса к переменной окружающего класса, после её инициализации с помощью вызова конструктора окружающего класса из конструктора локального класса, показывает её значение установленное  по умолчанию?

```
interface ITest{
  void getName();
}

class Test{
    private String name;

    Test(String name) {
        this.name=name;
    }
    Test() { }

        public ITest setName(String name1){
           class Test1 extends Test implements ITest{
               Test1 (String name) {
                   super(name1);
              }
              @Override
              public void getName(){
                 System.out.println(name);
             }
         }
        return new Test1(name1);
    }
}



public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test= new Test();
        ITest itest= test.setName("Имя");
        itest.getName();

    }
}
```

Вывод: null

Почему null ведь должен сработать конструктор локального класса и вызвать конструктор родителя с параметром где переменной окружающего класса задастся значение "Имя" ???

Comment: У меня код выводит "Имя" (хотя и по другой причине). Что я делаю не так? https://ideone.com/nCW9at

Comment: Исправил, теперь обращение к переменной класса а не к локальной.
Выводит null;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
System.out.println(name);
```

Здесь `name` — закрытое поле объекта `Test` в котором создан объект вложенного класса `Test1`.

Объект класса `Test` создан пустым конструктором:

```
Test test= new Test();
```

Соответственно, `name` для него не инициализировано и равно `null`.

Недоумение скорее всего вызвано тем, что `Test1` — потомок `Test` и унаследовал от него поле `name`. Это так, но это поле закрытое (`private`) и недоступно из `Test1`. Например, такой `getName` вызовет ошибку при компиляции:

```
public void getName(){
    System.out.println(this.name);
}
```

Если объявить `Test.name` как `protected`, то код выполнится ожидаемым образом.

Думаю понятнее будет рассмотреть поведение на двух разных поля:

```
//ITest и Main такие же
class Test {
    //инициализируется в конструкторе
    private String commonName;
    //используется только внутри Test 
    private String anotherName = "Another";

    Test(String arg1) {
        this.commonName = arg1;
    }

    Test() {
    }

    public ITest setName(String arg2) {
        class Test1 extends Test implements ITest {

            Test1(String arg3) {
                super(arg3);
            }

            @Override
            public void getName() {
                System.out.println(anotherName);
            }
        }
        return new Test1(arg2);
    }
}
```

Либо без наследования:

```
class Test {
    private String name = "Another";

    public ITest setName(String arg2) {
        class Test1 implements ITest {
            @Override
            public void getName() {
                System.out.println(name);
            }
        }
        return new Test1();
    }
}
```

Comment: Понял, спасибо.